# Low preformance levels with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap

I have noticeably low performance levels with my OpenGL project, sometimes slow enough to make the app crash. It runs on about 1 frame per second, but I'd prefer 20, or if possible I would like 60. So what my program does, is it takes a bitmap file, takes the red, green, and blue from one of the pixels, stores the same colored pixel in the HDC, resets the coordinates, and so on until it finishes all the pixels and it prints it on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
#include "bitmap_image.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
HDC Image(HDC hDC, string File_Name, int x_position, int y_position, int length, int height)
{
File_Name = "C:/Users/David/Pictures/" + File_Name + ".bmp";    
bitmap_image image(File_Name);      // Open the bitmap
unsigned char red;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char blue;
restart:
image.get_pixel(x_position, y_position, red, green, blue);     // Get the red green and blue from x_position and y_position and     store it in red green and blue. 
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);                                        // Make a pixel at x_position and y_position with red green and blue.
glColor3ub (red, green, blue);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glEnd();
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3ub (red, green, blue);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glEnd();
if (x_position==length)      // If x_position equals to length of bmp set x_position to 0 and add 1 to y_position.
{
if (y_position==height)      // If bmp is done loading go to done.
{
goto done;
}
x_position = 0;
y_position = y_position + 1;
}
x_position = x_position + 1;
goto restart;
done:         
return hDC;           
}

void Load_Image(HDC hDC)
{
SwapBuffers(hDC);                                  // Load the image
}

int main()
{
int x = 0;                                                                                                    
int y = 500;
HDC River = Image(hDC, "River", 0, 0, 1340, 678);                // make the river
HDC Turtle_1 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);            // make the turtle 10 pixels away on the river
x = x + 10;                                                                                              // push the turtle 10 more pixels
HDC Turtle_2 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);            // make the turtle 20 pixels away on the river
x = x + 10;                                                                                              // and so on... 
HDC Turtle_3 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_4 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_5 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_6 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_7 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_8 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_9 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_10 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_11 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_12 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_13 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_14 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_15 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_16 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_17 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_18 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_19 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
x = x + 10;
HDC Turtle_20 = Image(River, "Turtle", x, y, 95, 65);
Load_Image(Turtle_1);               // Load the images to make the video
Load_Image(Turtle_2);
Load_Image(Turtle_3);                                                               
Load_Image(Turtle_4);
Load_Image(Turtle_5);
Load_Image(Turtle_6);
Load_Image(Turtle_7);
Load_Image(Turtle_8);
Load_Image(Turtle_9);
Load_Image(Turtle_10);
Load_Image(Turtle_11);
Load_Image(Turtle_12);
Load_Image(Turtle_13);
Load_Image(Turtle_14);
Load_Image(Turtle_15);
Load_Image(Turtle_16);
Load_Image(Turtle_17);
Load_Image(Turtle_18);
Load_Image(Turtle_19);
Load_Image(Turtle_20);
}
```

Note #1 about the code: you can find bitmap_image.h at http://partow.net/programming/bitmap/

Note #2 about the code: I've left out the OpenGL functions, such as: EnableOpenGL, DisableOpenGL, etc.

Any solutions to making it any faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With that code you can use `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)` and get rid of about half of your gl calls.

But why are you manipulating individual pixels of a bitmap rather than setting that bitmap as a texture and letting the video hardware do all the work?

Comment: I am loading a bitmap from a file, and no tutorials I've found so far work for that. If you think that's what I should do, how would I go about it?

Comment: @wdt12 You'll ultimately want to use `glTexImage2D` but there's a lot of other gl calls to support it.

Comment: One more question: when I try to compile it I get this error - cannot convert 'std::string' to 'GLuint {aka unsigned int}' for argument '2' to 'void glBindTexture(GLenum, GLuint)'  Is there a certain way I need to put the file name? I am trying to load it from a 24-bit bitmap made with MS paint.

Comment: @wdt12 There's a whole series of steps to load the texture and get it set up and ready for use.  Consult www.opengl.org.

Answer (score -1):

Preloading the images, and directing yourself with a `valarray()` and using AI,by gsplice() adding bitmaps in conservative order, wherein your slowest fps comes from non preformatted movements would be quicker.

Think of it this way. You have 18 numbers. How many ways can you put them in order? And when can you start at a position between these orders, remember you've seen this one, and start that same sequence? Try 3 in a row. Then 4, then 5,and so on.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your saying... could you give me some code examples maybe?